# Android LiveData, Cannot create an instance of class viewModel

Tags: java, android, viewmodel, android-livedata

Following the example given by [android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata), I extended the ViewModel class

```
public class NameViewModel extends ViewModel {
private MutableLiveData<String> currentName;

public MutableLiveData<String> getCurrentName() {
    if (currentName == null) {
        currentName = new MutableLiveData<String>();
    }
    return currentName;
}}
```

and i observed the LiveData objects

```
public class NameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NameViewModel model;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Other code to setup the activity...

    // Get the ViewModel.
    model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NameViewModel.class);

    // Create the observer which updates the UI.
    final Observer<String> nameObserver = new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final String newName) {
            // Update the UI, in this case, a TextView.
            nameTextView.setText(newName);
        }
    };

    // Observe the LiveData, passing in this activity as the LifecycleOwner and the observer.
    model.getCurrentName().observe(this, nameObserver);
}}
```

and my dependencies in build.gradle are

```
dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Running this code is giving Cannot create an instance of class NameViewModel, what am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: Do you get a crash? Can you paste the logs (stacktrace) from logcat?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the constructor in the ViewModel class, so add `public NameViewModel() {};` to your ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems to be wrong with the code though.

Could you check if you have this particular dependency version in your build.gradle

```
 implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
```

and could you please add your build.gradle .

Answer (score 0):

Should you, perhaps, add an empty constructor in the `ViewModel` an call `super()` there?

Answer (score 0):

I had NameViewModel in the same java file as NameActivity, where it should be in separate file NameViewModel.java, this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead:**
`model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NameViewModel.class);`

**Try this:**
`model = new ViewModelProvider(this,new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication())).get(NameViewModel.class);`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.